# Setting integer values for spinner throws java.lang.NullPointerException in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to create an android app form with a spinner. The spinner xml is given below

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/no_of_nights"
style="@style/spinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/no_of_nights"
android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

The entries are populated from an arrays.xml file

```
<array name="no_of_nights">
        <item />
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>9</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>10-15 days</item>
        <item>15-20 days</item>
        <item>30 days</item>
    </array>
```

The app runs fine when there are no integer values ie 1 to 10, but when there are integer values, an exception is thrown

```
2021-11-12 21:45:03.189 20601-20601/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hornbill, PID: 20601
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:454)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
        at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:869)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:618)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7112)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25966)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:493)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25966)....
```

I am using Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The activity class is given below

```
package com.example.myapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class SurveyCreate extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey_create);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have found the cause of the error. If anyone wants to know, using `<string-array name="no_of_nights">` instead of `<array name="no_of_nights">` in the arrays.xml file fixed the issue

Comment: Can we see your code for setting up the spinner?

Comment: `The app runs fine when there are no integer values ie 1 to 10, ` ?? 1 to 10 look integer values to me. But what is your intention with `<item />`?

Comment: It is just to include a blank option in the list since the field is optional.